# How to access a variable using new Person(name, description)?

Tags: javascript, object

While looking at the Cookie Clicker source code I noticed a peculiar system of Game objects, he used new Game.Building("cursor"...). I then decided I would test this with my own code so I did the same thing with a basic user variable.

```
AI.User = function(username, password) {
    try {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

        this.setUsername = function(username) { this.username = username; };
        this.setPassword = function(password) { this.password = password; };
        this.getUsername = function() { return this.name; };
        this.getPassword = function() { return this.password; };
        this.GetUserByUsername = function(username) { };

        return true;
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    }
};
new AI.User("John Smith", "JSmith42");
```

The problem is I do not know how to access the variable created.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Should be `new AI.User` at least. And `GetUserByUsername` function makes no sense in this context.

Comment: I will work on that eventually in the actual code, it is simply there for when I get log-in and users working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Object-Oriented Programming in JavaScript

When you use a function with the `new` operator (i.e. as a constructor), it essentially wraps the function in a little extra code to create a new object, which it sets to `this`, and then returns that object at the end. **So to save the results of the call, you just assign it to a variable, like `var myUser = new AI.User("John Smith", "JSmith42");`

Getting into the details, you could think of it sort of like this. **The code I'm about to give isn't a perfect match for what actually goes on behind the scenes, but it covers the basics**:

```
function constructObject(constructor) {
    var newPrototype = constructor.prototype || Object.prototype,
        newThis = Object.create(newPrototype),
        constructorResult;

    constructor.apply(
        newThis,
        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)
    );
    if (constructorResult !== undefined) {
        return constructorResult;
    }
    return newThis;
}
```

When you call "new Constructor(a, b, c)", it's essentially like calling "constructObject(constructor, a, b, c)" as I mention here.

"Object.create" in line 2 creates a brand-new object, whose prototype is equal to whatever we pass in. Note that newPrototype gets picked up from from either `constructor.prototype` or, if that doesn't exist, `Object.prototype`. This "newPrototype" object then becomes the prototype of the object that we pass around.

"constructor.apply" then calls the constructor, with our `newThis` object set to `this` for that call, and passes in whatever other arguments we might have but leaves the constructor out. We save the return value of the function, even though it's bad practice for constructors to return anything.

**Here's a gotcha: if for some reason the constructor returned an object, then we return that instead of the object we made. Otherwise, we return our new object**. This is one of the big points where my code isn't a perfect match for what really happens, because the engine has better ways to examine what was or wasn't returned.

**It's not good practice to use `new` without saving the result in a variable**. It works, but it looks really strange, and I suspect this is part of why you were confused when you saw it.

### Object-Oriented Programming in Cookie Clicker

**Cookie Clicker essentially implements its own simple "OO-like" system on top of JavaScript's**. There are three kinds of objects: Game.Object, Game.Upgrade, and Game.Achievement. There's no inheritance, prototypal or otherwise, but because it works through a series of callback functions, there's still a kind of polymorphism.

**The `new` operator works just like it does in standard JavaScript**. The key is that all three of the basic constructors save a reference to `this` every time they're called, in one of three lists within the Game object. **That's how Cookie Clicker keeps tabs on the objects it creates without saving them in variables: it actually does, just not "in the open"**. The end result is almost like a kind of table (among other things, as the Game object is huge).

**It is probably not a good idea to imitate this style**. It reads like no other JavaScript code out there, which is probably a large part of why it confused you so much. Orteil himself seems to be moving away from it: the source code to Idle Game Maker (his follow-up engine) bears a strong resemblance to Cookie Clicker's, but the object system is gone. This is black magic: it's an interesting study in the esoteric details of JavaScript, but not something you should actually practice.

Which, given the themes of Cookie Clicker, is entirely appropriate.

Comment: Oh okay then, thank you for the explanation. This is good to know so I don't have to rewrite code later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking why create a variable like that, it's because it's a constructor for that variable.  Instead of creating a User object with no name or password and setting it later, you can just call the constructor and fill in the proper parameters with the values you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to use OO style in javascript.

You can refer to [this post](http://pivotallabs.com/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword/) if you like to read more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the result of the `new` expression in a variable:

```
var user = new AI.User("John Smith", "JSmith42");
console.log(user.getUsername();); // outputs "John Smith"
```

Note that you can also use a function's `.prototype` property to create your getters and setters once, rather than having to re-create them every time someone creates a new object. Here's an example of that from [an article I wrote](https://www.codementor.io/javascript-tutorial/top-ten-things-beginners-must-know-javascript):

```
function Person(first, last)
{
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
}
var john = new Person("John", "Doe");
var mary = new Person("Mary", "Deer");
Person.prototype.full = function() {return this.first + " " + this.last;};
alert(john.full()); // "John Doe"
```

> There are a lot of things happening here.
>
> 1. We create a `function`, which will set properties on its `this` object when called.
> 2. We create two separate instances of that function by putting the `new` keyword before our function calls. This ensures that `john` and `mary` refer to completely separate objects, each with their own `first` and `last` properties.
> 3. We create a new function and assign it to the `full` property on our `Person` function's `prototype` property. The `prototype` property exists on all functions, and allows you to define fall-back properties that should exist on every object created from that function.
> 4. We call the `full()` function on `john`. JavaScript sees that the `john` object doesn't actually have a `full` function on it, so it looks for a `Person.prototype.full()` function and calls that instead. Within that call, however, `this` still refers to the `john` object.